# Excel DAO Query Using a Range of Cells as Parameters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using VBA to query a database. I am using a FOR EACH loop to iterate through the range that contains the values for the parameters. This works okay for most of what i am trying to accomplish, but it seems inefficient because of the number of database calls that must be made. Is there a way to make the query accept the range of cells as the query parameters in the query WHERE clause or perhaps a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Questions are always improved by showing the actual code you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably going to get flamed for this, but so be it.....

I wrote an excel function that concatenates a range of cells into a delimited string for use in SQL `IN` statements. You can find the whole code on [my blog](http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/excel-sqlconcat-function-revisited/). Use my sqlConcat() function to genereate a string to concatenate into your sql statement as part of an `IN` clause.

Concatenation is not best practice, and it really is open to injection. So, I don't know how much I support running my function through code this way, but it will help you do what you're asking.